# Javafx + Scala, расположение элементов по координатам

Tags: javafx, scala

Пытался разными способами вручную задать расположение элемента(кнопки) в окне(пытаюсь несколько кнопок последовательно поставить друг за другом). Последовательно создаю три кнопки, но на экране отображается только последняя и отрабатывает нажатие только она. Нашел метод `setLayoutX` который вроде позволяет установить расположение по оси X, но это не помогает, элемент находятся в верхнем левом углу(видимо все три там, друг под другом).
Если вместо `GridPane` использовать `StackPane` , то элемент находится в центре, тоже только один. В общем не могу понять в чем дело)

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.event.ActionEvent
import javafx.event.EventHandler
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import javafx.stage.Stage
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text;
import javafx.scene.control;
import javafx.scene.paint;
import javafx.geometry;

object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String])
  {
    val witchers: List[String] = new List();
    witchers.AddBack("The Witcher")
    witchers.AddBack("The Witcher 2")
    witchers.AddBack("The Witcher 3")

    Application.launch(classOf[Main], args: _*)
  }
}

class Main extends Application {

  override def start(primaryStage: Stage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("For Romanov")
    var buttons = new List[Button]
    val pane = new GridPane//StackPane

    val witchers: List[String] = new List();
    witchers.AddBack("The Witcher")
    witchers.AddBack("The Witcher 2")
    witchers.AddBack("The Witcher 3")

    var layoutX = 5.toDouble;
    for (witcher <- witchers) {
      var btn = new Button
      btn.setText(witcher)
      btn.setLayoutX(layoutX)
      btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
        override def handle(e: ActionEvent) {
          println(witcher)
        }
      })
      var hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(javafx.geometry.Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
      //pane.getChildren.add(btn)
        pane.add(hbBtn, 40, 40)
      layoutX += 100
    }    

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 500))
    primaryStage.show
  }

}
```

Comment: Используйте `HBox` или `FlowPane` в качестве родительского нода и не будет проблем

Comment: @AndreyM но в коде в вопросе я и использовал HBox, другой вопрос правильно ли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("For Romanov")
    val pane = new HBox
    val witchers: List[String] = List("The Witcher","The Witcher 2","The Witcher 3");
    for (witcher <- witchers) {
      var btn = new Button(witcher)
      btn.setOnAction(ae => println(witcher));
      pane.getChildren.add(btn)
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 500))
    primaryStage.show
  }
```

Comment: Не совсем ответ на вопрос, но он показал мою ошибку) Всё дело в GridPane (таблица)